# Default accessibility level of a new class

Tags: c#

When we create a new c# class in Visual Studio, it always has an internal access modifier; why can't it be public?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuM1f.png)

Maybe I'm missing something, but when we define entities (POCO) that are exposed to other projects, we have to change the accessibility level from internal to public, or is there a way to change that behaviour of VS?

Comment: This is the default because it's considered best practice to start with `internal` and only make things `public` if you really need to. A large public API means that changes later on have to be more careful to not break the public API that other code might depend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item you create in Visual Studio is done by using something called a "template" file. While you can define your own templates for pretty much any file, there are standard templates already shipped with VS, e.g. a C# class.

If you search the following directory:

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio{year}{edition}\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\

You will find a file "Class.cs". This is the template file VS is using when you selected "Class" as a new item to add to your project.

You can now change this file according to your needs or create a new item template.

Comment: In light of Logarr's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157103/default-accessibility-level-of-a-new-class#comment134305386_76157103), this should not be done.

Comment: @madreflection While I agree with you and Logarr, the question OP asked was if the behavior of VS can be changed to do what OP wants, not if it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: True, you answered the question that was asked. It still needed the caveat, though.

Comment: Thank you @logarr, axs for responses, what about your thoughts on making default accessibility as public for example in standard library projects and if required changing access modifier to more restricted.